# Find All 'Rental' that dont have 'Bookings' within a given DateRange

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord, rails-activerecord

## **Proposal**

What im trying to do, is allow people to input a date range, and find all 'Rentals' places that have open days between the provided date range from the user.

My Rentals have a has_many association with "bookings" which contain a start and end date.

What would be the best possible way to get every rental article that has a day that is open within that range.

## **Issue**

I can find all the Rentals that have Bookings that dont overlap with the given time, but that doesnt account for each day. So if there was a booking from 7 Sept to 10 Sept, and the User entered the range 5 Sept to 9 Sept, that record would simply not be included, but in theory there is the 5th-7th open.

## **My Possible Solution**

Im still thinking this problem through, so i have not started coding. But what i was going to do, is find all the Rentals that DONT have bookings that overlap with the provided Date Range, store those in a variable(because these are correct results, because it means not a single day overlaps).

Then i will find all the Rentals that have bookings that DO overlap with the provided Date Range. I will then loop through those bookings, and within that, loop through the Range of Dates provided by the user(DateRange.Each) and check if each single day is within that bookings date ranges, as soon as a single day results in a false value(meaning at least one day doesnt overlap) it will end the loop and add the associated "rental" article to the articles collected early with no overlaps at all.

## **Concerns**

The only issue i have with this solution, is i feel it might not be very optimized or run well, im not sure. At the worst case, i would have hundreds of "rentals' and im not sure how many different "Bookings". I dont think something like this could be done in a single SQL query could it ?

## **Sample data**

```
Rentals Model
name: string
has_many Bookings


Bookings Model
rental_id: integer
start_date: Date
end_date: Date
```

The user inputs a DateRange, i want all Rentals that have open days(none taken by a 'Booking' in the range provided.

## **EDIT**

I have been thinking, and i think the best solution is using postgres db, which allows for arrays. Ill then store all the dates of the booking, in the array, instead of storing the range.

Postgres supports checking if all the values in an given array is present in an array in the DB. So i could check if the array of 'wanted days' is 'contained' by a DB array, if it is, it means none of the days are free.

Comment: Have you considered representing a "bookings" as a set of "booking" records, each with a property and a date? That would making finding properties that do/don't have a booking associated with them trivial.

Comment: The Bookings are records. This issue is that the bookings are variable in size. It could be a day, a week, or 3 days.

I assume you are saying i could rather store the dates as single dates ? so the Booking record would have "dates" instead of a 'start_date" and "end_date". I guess i could set it up like this, but wouldnt that cause issues with long bookings ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Provided some usable sample data i think.

Comment: If you have 100 properties, and all of them are rented out everyday for 50 years, you'll still have under 2 million booking records. That's trivial for postgres to manage. Exploding bookings into individual dates might be a bit more work when you initially rent out a property because you're creating multiple records, but the pay off is letting the database doing what's it's good at, and keeping Ruby from doing what it's poor/slow at.

Comment: @ToddR Im having to agree with you here. So would the best course of action be to change the bookings from having a start and end date, and rather have a postgres array of Dates  that the booking involves.

Or should i go the route of creating a whole new model for 'Booking Days" ?

Comment: I would create a record for each day a property is rented (call this a "booked_day" if you want) - this also allows you to have different rates for each date if you later choose. Each booked_day would have an booking_id and date - each booking would have a property_id and probably information about who is actually renting the property.

Comment: @ToddR Alright im going to give that a try. As it stands, i use scopes to find properties for a filter using.  

`props = Property.where(nil)`  

`props = props.in_city(params[:f_city]) if params[:f_city].present?`

Comment: @ToddR
I was wondering how i would go about checking for properties with open days within a given period. So user will enter a range, we have a array of days from this range. Do i just set up a scope on the booked_day model, and call it like so ? `props.Bookings.Booked_days.freedays(userarray)`.  

with freedays(userarray) being a scope on booked_days.

Comment: I currently work on a rails app, but to be honest, I wouldn't use active record for this (or really for anything that I can do directly with the database). I'd start by trying something like "select p.* from properties p inner join bookings b on b.property_id = p.id left outer join booked_days bd on bd.booking_id = b.id where bd.day in (date1, date2, etc) and bd.id is null" (this is obviously pseudo-sql, but hopefully gives you an idea). If you're hell bent on letting active record write your sql, you'll have to get help from someone else. Sorry

Comment: @ToddR Im not that great with raw SQL haha, but hopefully someone around here will see this post and use the info you provided to help me created a activerecord query.

Thanks for your time mate :)